# Portable(in USB drive) C# CRUD apps

Tags: c#-4.0, portable-applications

I need to write app from C# that do CRUD with database.and also it shuld look up for .net framework and install it if particular pc doesn't have it.user must be able to do crud things from the place he finished in previous computer
can you suggest me:

1. Database to use
2. Any class libraries for this
3. Any special considerations

I m using vs 2010 with .net framwork 4

Comment: Generally speaking, for portable, single user apps, SQLite would be the easiest database to use. However, your question is actually many questions in one (e.g. a portable .net installer is quite a wide topic in itself)

Answer (score 0):

A bit offtopic:
Actually "portable app" philosophy mean not only it could run without any installation process but also it will not leave any trails after itself. It including various frameworks installation.

To avoid any installations or registry trails - check portableapps.com, they have pretty neat toolset to make any app portable. They have Java-vm solution for sure, don't remember about .NET solution.